# What's the default Return behavior for a brightscript function?

Tags: roku, brightscript

So I was looking through an older brightscript codebase and found a bunch of `functions` which are returning things, but not specifying what they are returned `as`.

For example:

```
function logMessage(prefix as string, message as string)
  concatenatedMessage = prefix + message

  if m.top.logLevel <= m.top.verbosity
    print concatenatedMessage
  end if
  return concatenatedMessage
end function
```

So what's happening here? Clearly a string is being sent back, so is it acting exactly the same as if it had been declared `function logMessage(prefix as string, message as string) as string`? or `as object`?

I had been under the (false?) impression that if you left off `as _____` from your functions, they were `as void` by default, the same as a `sub` is. But this is working, I'm just not sure how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since BrighScript supports dynamic typing (like JavaScript), the default return type of a function is "Dynamic".

From the [docs](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/language/program-statements.md#functionparameter--default-as-type--as-type--end-function):

> The return type of the function may also be declared. If the parameter
>   or return type are not declared, they are assumed to be "dynamic"